# Eigenvalues of $SL(n, \mathbb Z)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Is it true that if an eigenvalue of $M \in SL(n, \mathbb Z)$ is on the unit circle, then it's argument must be a rational multiple of $\pi$?

I apologise for poor typesetting. I am using my phone. I will make the edits as soon as I have access to a computer.

Comment: I wonder if this is known for $n \ge 3$?  I wonder they would say over on MO?

Answer (score 4):

The eigenvalues of $M$ are solutions of
$$ X^2-\operatorname{tr}(M) X+ \det(M)=0.$$
With $\det(M)=1$ and $\operatorname{tr}(M)\in\Bbb Z$, one (and hence both) solutions can only be on the unit circle if $\operatorname{tr}(M)\in\{-2,-1,0,1,2\}$. Three of these cases correspond to $\lambda_{1,2}=1$, $\lambda_{1,2}=\pm i$, $\lambda_{1,2}=-1$, whereas $X^2\pm X+1=0$ leads to $X^3\mp1=0$ after multiplying by $X\mp1$, so the eigenvalues are third or sixth roots of unity and their arguments are multiples of $\frac\pi3$.

Comment: I'm so sorry I meant to ask for SL(n,Z). I edited the question. Thank you anyways!